# How do I find a span with a specific class that contains an exact string of text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to find the following node within a page:

```
<span class="dotted">Admin</span>
```

I've tried the following jQuery selectors, but neither seem to work in selecting the node:

```
$(".dotted span:contains('Admin')").css("color","red");
$("span:contains('Admin') .dotted").css("color","red");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: separating a tag and a class with a space means that the 2nd selector is a descendant of the first.  So what its looking for in your selector is a child span of .dotted

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This selector should do what you want.

```
$("span.dotted:contains('Admin')")
```

Remember you can chain Tag names with IDs and classes. Example

```
$("span#yourID")
```

OR

```
$("span.yourclass")
```

OR a mixture of the two

```
$("span#yourID.yourClass")
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is very helpful, beyond just providing the answer.  I'm still trying to get the hang of how to chain stuff together.

Comment: @Ben...I have a handy jQuery Cheat Sheet that I use. you can find it here http://labs.impulsestudios.ca/downloads/impulse_studios-jquery_cheat_sheet-1.0.pdf  In addition remember the selectors are very similar to CSS selectors (Not exactly the same but similar)

Comment: that's a really cool cheat sheet! I'm printing it out now and will put it in its own corner on my desk.